# Symfony2/Doctrine: How to persist an entity from the entity class?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1

**Short Description of the problem:**
I generate a file inside the entity class and would like to save the filename to the database. The controller doesn't know about this (wheter or not the filename has changed, so it's not practical to persist from the controller.

Is there a way for an Entity to persist itself?

**Example of my use:**
The entity class is for an image in a gallery. I always keep the original file and work with a cached version of the file. When the image is changed (rotated for example), the cached version is deleted. The cached version also be deleted in other cases. When the file is needed, I check if the cached file exists, otherwise it is regenerated with a new filename from the archived image. I need a new filename because that resets the cache for various thumbnail sizes.

When I generate that new file, I have to save its filename to the database somehow. Because it is only decided in the Entity when to regenerate the image, it would be practical if the entity could persist itself to the database, but I haven't found a solution for that.

Is there a way to do this or is there a whole different concept I should be using to regenerate the image file?

Comment: Don't get the problem.  You persist entity only once, then you work with a entity that doctrine creates for you. If you have an entity with two fields [orig_filename, cached_filename] and that entity is managed by doctrine, then when you change any property it will automatically update the database on flush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities in Doctrine are not [active records](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) - they cannot perform persistance actions by themselves, so they rely on a Big Brother [the entity manager].

Even if the controller doesn't know wether any filename as changed or not, **you** do - just persist your picture every time: if nothing changed, Doctrine won't touch the entity.

Have a look at [lifecycle events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) too, maybe you can find useful to fire a `@PreUpdate` method before persistance [e.g. generating thumbnails].

Comment: I kind of expected that, but thanks for the exact explanation. Persisting from the controller is not really an option because the regeneration of the file can actually also be triggered by a template (entity.getWebPath if the file doesn't exist).

**BUT**: Using lifecyce events could be a really goo idea, it could work to regenerate the file on postLoad instead of when I want to display it.

Comment: Aaaarg, I'm new to Stackoverfow and it saved my comment too early... 

I'm going with postLoad, then the file will be generated before I render the template and I can persist from the controller. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Nothing to do with you question, just to let you know that if you save a comment (or a question or an answer) too early, you can just edit it and modify it, no need to add a new comment